# Angular 2 router navigate function not working

Tags: angular

I have a problem with the router function "navigate", in my AppComponent I have :

```
@RouteConfig([ 
  {path:'/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent,  useAsDefault: true, data: {user: null}},
  {path:'/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
])
```

In my HomeComponent, I am trying to do this :

```
...
constructor(private _router:Router){}

changePage(){
  this._router.parent.navigate(["Dashboard"]); // It fails
}
...
```

It doesn't send me at '/dashboard', is this normal ?

Comment: Is it `dashboardComponent` or `DashboardComponent`?

Comment: It is DashboardComponent, my bad

Answer (score 5):

I have finally found ! It's working with :

```
changePage() {
  this._router.navigate(["../Dashboard"]);
}
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: You should use full path for navigate not relative when u use
this.router.navigate(['someroute']) //is relative
this.router.navigate(['/someroute']) //is absolute try this one

Answer (score 4):

why using parent ? it should be `this._router.navigate(["Dashboard"]);`

Answer (score 1):

router.navigate is a method which take path as a parameter and navigate to that particular path and load component, I hope it will work.

```
constructor(private _router:Router){}
changePage(){
this._router.navigate(["dashboard"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message ?

Also why using `this._router.parent.navigate` rather than simply `this._router.navigate..` ?

Comment: I tried just  `this._router.navigate`, it didn't work , but I think I should use "parent" because this._router is a ChildRouter

Comment: There is no error message,it just redirects me on the same page

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following to use a route defined in the `AppComponent` component:

```
changePage() {
  this._router.navigate(["/Dashboard"]);
}
```

Comment: During 1 second it puts "?" in my url :  _http://localhost:3000/home?_, and it redirects me on the same page